# Which cooling pad to get for Macbook pro 15 Early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, cooling

I am playing games on my Mac. and the machine gets red hot. I'd like to get a cooling pad for it to keep it calm. After doing a lot of searching I'm thinking of getting a [CoolMaster Notepal Infinite Evo](http://www.coolermaster.com/product.php?product_id=6695)

Will this cooling pad work well for my machine? I am not able to get much variety of cooling pads in my area. Also, I am attaching links to other cooling pads available:[Link 1](http://www.galaxy.com.pk/form044.html) , [Link 2](http://www.czone.com.pk/laptop-accessories-laptop-cooling-pads-pakistan-pt.206.aspx).

Comment: Why do you think you need a cooling pad? A Mac is perfectly capable of handling the high temperatures. And in case it gets too hot, it will shut itself down to cool down properly. Just make sure you don't play those games on a pillow or blanket where you'll cover up the ventilation holes...

Comment: There are no ventilation holes in uni body macs :(, they get burning hot

Comment: Oh, there are :-) There is the display hinge for starters. And it even uses every port available (USB, FireWire,...) to get some fresh air inside the Mac.

Comment: Oh okies, never noticed that as I am always scared that the machine may explode coz of intense heating :), that means useless to buy cooling pad

Comment: A Mac can get 100°C very easily. So, don't get afraid too fast. As I said, a Mac is perfectly capable of handling it's own cooling process.

Comment: Not really. Have 2x27" displays attached to a rMBP and when it hits 105˚C (which it does after a few minutes because the GPU procudes too much heat, thus also affecting the CPU), the kernel_task keeps hogging all CPU to prevent further overheating. So... cooling pads ARE needed.

Comment: @Michiel No, these MBPs are well documented as NOT being able to handle the high temperatures.  So many 2011 MBPs have dying GPUs due to the poor design of the laptop.

Comment: Yes, they don't deal with heat well. I've had my computer shut down from overheating before. Instead of getting a cooling pad, I use [macs fan control](https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) to start my fan if my second CPU core reaches C65* and goes to maximum at C75*

Comment: Also, macs fan control is free